# StatusBar color display weird in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat

When I am running my Application.My Status bar background color display weird. I don't know why this happen.

[image]

As you can see in the Top the black shadow color display like the `Gradient` type.

As this device has `Kitkat` version then why it display `black` color.

Is this bug or something Any help be Appreciated ?

**layout_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
                android:src="@drawable/gargi_logo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textinputLayout_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin50"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_logo">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_username_editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textinputLayout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textinputLayout_username"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin5">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_password_editText"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textinputLayout_password"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin40"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin40" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_forgetpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
                android:text="@string/forget_password"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin10" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/signUp_textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/register_now"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin10"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>
```

And this my `LoginActivity` so I use this theme

> AppTheme.NoActionBar

**UpDate :**

I have created new Google Kitkat device which is display the same result

[image]

Comment: Its status bar color cannot change in the Kitkat

Comment: @Nithinlal I know but why is display `Gradient` type color and `Top`.

Comment: which phone r u checking , check whether all the application have the same color status bar. IF yes its your theme issue

Comment: That's the standard look on KitKat.

Comment: @Nithinlal other Application don't have any color its only black color. And as  can say `statusBar` don't have color then why my `statusBar` have color ??

Comment: @MikeM. Sir it  means we can't change it right ?

Comment: Yes we can't change its color Ironman below 5.0

Comment: Oh, you mean why is that there at all? You might have `fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your layout. Remove that, if you just want the plain, black status bar.

Comment: @MikeM. If I remove that then also it will display the same thing.

Comment: It might be on multiple `View`s in your layout. Make sure to remove them all. Also, check your code, see if you're setting it there anywhere. You might need to clean and rebuild.

Comment: @MikeM. I have update my question. you can check it ? and also same output as I `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project.

Comment: @Ironman what is you current  base theam

Comment: @Nithinlal checkout my update question ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you make sure it's not in your code anywhere? Did you try cleaning/rebuilding?

Comment: @MikeM. yes I try to `clean` and `Rebuild` the Project.

Comment: Dunno. I just dropped that into an empty project, and ran it on KitKat, and there's no gradient effect for me.

Comment: @MikeM. I also suprise with this thing ??

Comment: Maybe it's just the emulator. You might try explicitly setting `fitsSystemWindows="false"`. Other than that, all I can suggest is to test it elsewhere, like another emulator, or on a device.

Comment: @MikeM. ok Let me try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129097/discussion-between-ironman-and-mike-m).

Comment: @MikeM. same result see my update question. In the new device the black color display as `DarkBlack`.

Comment: Well, by "device", I meant an actual, physical device. Try testing a bare minimum project, with just an `Activity`. If it does it there, then it's probably your emulator. If not, then, I guess, start adding pieces of the problem project until it appears.

Answer (score 1):

The status bar is a system window owned by the operating system. On pre-5.0 Android devices, applications do not have permission to alter its color, so this is not something that the AppCompat library can support for older platform versions. The best AppCompat can do is provide support for coloring the ActionBar and other common UI widgets within the application.

Comment: I know but why is display `Gradient` type color and `Top`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most impact out of your content, you can now use new window styles and themes to request translucent system UI, including both the status bar and navigation bar. To ensure the legibility of navigation bar buttons or status bar information, subtle gradients is shown behind the system bars. A typical use-case would be an app that needs to show through to a wallpaper. - REASON ;)